# Why user mostly drops from shipping address page in checkout?

Tags: e-commerce, checkout, conversion, conversion-rate

We have a 4 step checkout process in our ecommerce website.

1. Login/Signup
2. Shipping Address
3. Delivery date and special instructions
4. Payment

Here we have a checkout conversion of around 40%. Means if 100 people signup on our website only 40 will place order. Now we were analyzing behaviour of rest of 60% people who drop from checkout. And we found out that out of these 60 people who dropped, 50% people did not filled their shipping address, they simply signup and leave checkout on shipping address page.

We are not able to understand, why such a big number of people are leaving without doing any activity in checkout. What could be the possible areas where we can improve upon to reduce this number?

Comment: Speculation at this stage: are there restrictions on where you can deliver that aren't apparent until _after_ they have signed-up and come to enter the delivery address? (E.g. "_Note: We can only ship to locations in the Central African Republic_" at the top of the "_Enter Shipping Address_" page).

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible reasons, but without seeing your site or that specific page, it’s just a bunch of wild guesses:

- You have restrictions on where you ship (e.g. only to the US when you have a global audience). Check your traffic per location, and check conversion rates (and exits on that page) per location.
- You have unreasonable restrictions, like requiring a state for countries that do not use one, input fields that are too short, requiring a phone number in a specific format...
- Your customers thought this would be a digital download or something like that. Really depends on the product.
- There’s something broken in your input validation and it just does not work on some browsers. Or mobile devices.

Check your analytics to see if there’s a correlation between exit rates and other parameters (country, browser, mobile...).

You may also want to record what fields were entered (even if the form wasn’t submitted), you may discover a field that has more issues than others.

You may also want to use click-recording services which will let you see how users behave on that page. It can be very instructive.

Another thing you can add is a chat to help people having issues with the form.

Comment: I would add one more point to this great answer - maybe only on that page the customers learn about the shipping costs and suddenly the price isn't so interesting - this happens to me quite often and that's why I often abandon purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Usually on Ecommerce sites lot of people just add products to cart to see how cart is looking with price all together and then drop off.

On checkout itself possible errors are to leave out information for delivery time, and delivery cost. This should be visible straight on cart overview at least, and before checkout starts. So that users dont need to start checkout for thoose info.

Afaik 40 <> 60 percent for a checkout drop out is normal. I cant guess why so much is Shipping step. Maybe to much fields? Do you provide some info there that turns people down? Are you sure all technically is correct there?

What you can do, as you already on shipping step have users e-mail from first step, is to send them e-mail reminder that they can finish checkout.